# Change Password In SQLite Database in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm using SQLite Database for insert , create or update data in my application.I want to change the password in my SQLite database.I'm having problem for change the password in my app. When I run the demo and enter the whatever field is there and hit the Button for change the data in database it goes to else condition. Nothing to show any error or exceptions in log cat. Is there any way to do that? Here is my code.

This is my DBHelper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(DataBase_Adapter.DATABASE_CREATE_LOGIN);
     }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {
            // Log the version upgrade.
      Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to "+_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

           _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");

            onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

This DataBaseAdapter Class Code

```
 public static final String TABLE_NAME_LOGIN="LOGIN";

        //Colum,n Names
        public static final String KEY_LOGIN_ID="ID";
        public static final String KEY_USERNAME="USERNAME";
        public static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID="EMAILID";
        public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="PASSWORD";


        //Table Create Statement 
        public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_LOGIN = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_LOGIN+" ("+KEY_LOGIN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_USERNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_EMAIL_ID+" TEXT, "+KEY_PASSWORD+" TEXT)";


 //Insert Data in Database Login
        public void insertEntry(String userName,String userEmail,String password)
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            newValues.put(KEY_USERNAME , userName);
            newValues.put(KEY_EMAIL_ID , userEmail);
            newValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD , password);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME_LOGIN, null, newValues);

        }


//Update Query

        public boolean change(String strEmailId , String strNewPin1 )
        {

            Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME_LOGIN +" SET " + KEY_PASSWORD+ " = '"+strNewPin1+"' WHERE "+ KEY_EMAIL_ID +"=?", new String[]{strEmailId});

            if (cur != null)
            {           
                if(cur.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This is my Change Pin Activity

```
public class Change_Pin_Activity7 extends Activity
{
    EditText editText_EmailId , editText_changePin1 , editText_changePin2;
    Button buttonChangePin;
    TextView textView_PasswordMatch;

    String strEmailId , strNewPin1 , strNewPin2;
    boolean storedNewData;

    DataBase_Adapter dbAdapter;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change_pin_activity7);

        dbAdapter=new DataBase_Adapter(this);
        dbAdapter=dbAdapter.open();

        editText_EmailId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_EmailId);
        editText_changePin1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pin1);
        editText_changePin2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pin2);

        textView_PasswordMatch=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_PinProblem);

        buttonChangePin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ChangePin);
        buttonChangePin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                strEmailId = editText_EmailId.getText().toString().trim();
                strNewPin1 = editText_changePin1.getText().toString().trim();
                strNewPin2 = editText_changePin2.getText().toString().trim();

                storedNewData=dbAdapter.change(strEmailId , strNewPin1);

                if (strNewPin1.equals(storedNewData)) 
                {

                    textView_PasswordMatch.setText("Password Match !!!");

                    Toast.makeText(Change_Pin_Activity7.this,
                            "Pin Change Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if(strEmailId.equals("")||strNewPin1.equals("")||strNewPin2.equals(""))
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                }

                // check if both password matches
                if(!strNewPin1.equals(strNewPin2))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pin does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Working ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        dbAdapter.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your actual problem? I'm little confused. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When is `if (strNewPin1.equals(storedNewData))` ever going to succeed, if `strNewPin1` is a `String`, and `storedNewData` is a `boolean`.

Comment: Yes you are right but when storedNewData is a String then it shows "type mismatch cannot convert from boolean to string " so then how to define storedNewData as a string and also change the return type of change() method in my DataBaseAdapter class.

Comment: What do you want me to say? You're comparing a string to a boolean, it will never succeed. Think of a flow that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not comparing string to a boolean I, saying it shows error.I know it will never succeed.